# Medical Physiology

Tags: physiology, neurophysiology, pharmacology, human-physiology, neuroanatomy

I've come across the topic of the influence of inhaled ammonia (caustic ammonia) on breathing rate and some cardiovascular changes. All of this stuff is thought to be mediated through the fifth cranial nerve (CNV). I found some articles about:
(1) https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK11036/
(2) https://journals.physiology.org/doi/abs/10.1152/ajplegacy.1928.87.2.319
but the key point here is the **scheme of reflex**. Are there any articles or textbooks, that contain an explanation of such phenomena from a neurophysiological point of view? Thanks.

Comment: Possibly better suited to medical science stack.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to have a descriptive title that includes your actual question, not an extremely broad category.